# create an Instance of MaincAtivity class in another class in android

Tags: android

hey guys I am creating a game in android using Eclipse and I want to create an instance of MainActivity class in another class so that I can use MainAcitivity class methods in another class. Can some one help me please...
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make your methods static..

Comment: @akash93 Never make Activity methods static

Comment: You should not create an instance of any Activity.  Activities should only be launched via intents.  Instead, put your common methods into a base activity class then extend the base class in your other activities.

Comment: pass an instance of it to the class

Comment: Because an activity can be destroyed by the OS in all kinds of scenarios.

Comment: @akash93 : I'm guessing you're not an Android programmer. The Android `Activity` class isn't just a Java POJO - it has a life-cycle which needs to be managed by the OS. It's impossible to create a functioning `Activity` using `new` (for example) and as Simon points out, there is no guarantee that any given instance of an `Activity` will exist in a stable state at any given time.

Comment: @Squonk yes I've just started learning android. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    protected void someCommonMethod{
    }

}
```

Then extend it:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{

    public override onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ....

        super.someCommonMethod();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think there's no need to use `super.` .

Comment: There isn't, but it makes the code more opaque.

Comment: @Simon I know this one and thanks for help but I want to know how to create instance of mainactivity

Comment: You should not.  This is the correct solution.  Only create Activities using `Intent`.

Comment: @Simon : Actually I'm with 'm lav' WRT there being no need for using `super`. How often do you start an `Activity` using `super.startActivity(...)` for example? Also the code example for `BaseActivity` is flawed - make `someCommonMethod()` protected rather than public and you also need a return 'type' as well as () on the method definition. Also in your `MyActivity` example, you're calling `someCommonMethod()` in the `Activity` body (which is before  full creation of the `Activity`) - better to show it from within a local method instead.

Comment: Thanks, missed the return type, edited now.